# Change Website a customer is associated too

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, customer-account, websites

in the past we had one store for Customers and Wholesale. We have now created a second store in the installation of magento. So 1 Installation, two stores.
I would like the wholesellers which are now associated to the Customer store to be changed that their account only works on the wholesale store.

Is there a way in doing this. At the moment its just greyed out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can by directly editing the `website_id` column values in the `customer_entity` table in your database.

It's not possible in the backend, as it's greyed out as you noted.

Remember to also change the `store_id` column value, to a store ID that is related to the newly entered website ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can use web debug tools from your browser and active the input field in the back end. Or change it in the database.

Anyway it is disabled for a reason. Not sure why but it might break something.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225176/how-to-move-customer-from-one-website-to-another-in-magento

Comment: It's not going to break anything. If you're configured to share customers across all websites then you'll be fine. If you are configured to not share customers across websites, there will be a unique constraint on email address and website id, and if you try to move a customer to a website where that email already exists you'll get a unique constraint violation error. I guess disabling this field was easier then handling that error in a user friendly way